# Swift cycle which compare times

Tags: swift, loops, while-loop, cycle

i have a schedule time and current time. I should write cycle which compare times. Cycle should print or send notification when schedule time equals to current time.

```
var schedule : String = "12.22.00"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "HH.mm.ss"
let calendar = Calendar.current
let minutesago = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute, value: +2, to: Date())!
let res = formatter.string(from: minutesago)

while true {
    if res == schedule {
        notificate()
        print("isequl")
    }
}
```

Comment: `res` will never equal `schedule` because they are in different formats and neither value ever changes.

Comment: but both of them in string format

Comment: Add this: `print(res)`. Notice how it is different from `schedule`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a good way to work but here is little modification in your code:

```
var schedule : String = "12.19.00"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "HH.mm.ss"
while true {
    let date = Date()
    let res = formatter.string(from: date)
    if res == schedule
    {
        print("isequl")
        break
    }
    sleep(10000)
}
```

You are getting current time only once so `res == schedule` will never be true. And you are using different format in then your string value. Your string is `hh.mm.ss` and formatter is `hh.mm`

**EDIT**

To do that you should use timer. First get time interval and then pass it in Timer as:

```
let date = Date().addingTimeInterval(interval)
let timer = Timer(fireAt: date, interval: 0, target: self, selector: #selector(runCode), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
```

Comment: This would block the CPU and not really work. You would have to sleep for some time in every iteration.